# How to make ruby object attributes hidden from inspect

Tags: ruby

So I like to use ruby `inspect` for debugging, however I have a class that have an array that have 6000+ elements and whenever I `puts obj.inspect` the array clutters the entire screen. Is there any way to make the array attribute hidden from inspect?

```rb
class Test
  def initialize
    @x = 1
    @array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  end

  def myinspect
    # ??
  end
end

c = Test.new
puts c.inspect # <Test:0x00007f1d49e33b00 @x=1, @array=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]>
puts c.myinspect # <Test:0x00007f1d49e33b00 @x=1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've decided to make an `inspect_except`

```rb
class Test
  def initialize
    @x = 1
    @array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  end

  def inspect_except(*attrs)
    r = "<#{self.class.name}:#{object_id}"
    instance_variables.each do |var|
      next if attrs.include? var
      r += " #{var}=#{instance_variable_get var}"
    end
    r += ">"
  end
end

c = Test.new
puts c.inspect_except(:@array)
```

Comment: A small point: it would be more succinct and arguably reads better to replace `next if attrs.include? var;  r += " #{var}=#{instance_variable_get var}"` with `r += " #{var}=#{instance_variable_get var}" unless attrs.include? var`.

Answer (score 4):

You can redefine any method in Ruby.
So, in your case, you may just redefine `inspect` in your class `Test`.

Here is an example.

```rb
class Test
  alias_method :inspect_original, :inspect if ! self.method_defined?(:inspect_original)  # backup

  def inspect
    content = instance_variables.map{|i|
      sprintf("%s=%s", i, instance_variable_get(i).inspect) if i != :@array
    }.compact.join(" ")
    "<#{self.class.name}:0x#{object_id.to_s(16).rjust(16, '0')} #{content}>"
  end
end

Test.new.inspect
# => "<Test:0x00000000001fb490 @x=1>"
```

Comment: There is no need for `"[EDIT]"`. It's merely a distraction. When editing just make changes without mentioning you have done so.

Answer (score 3):

To use `my_inspect` we need the following regular expression, which I've written in free-spacing mode to make it self-documenting.

```
R = /
    ,\ @  # match ', @'
    \w+   # match one or more word characters
    =\[   # match '=['
    .*?   # match one or more characters lazily
    \]    # match ']'
    /x    # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

This is conventionally written

```
R = /, @\w+=\[.*?\]/
```

---

We then create the class `Test` to contain one instance variable holding an integer and two instance variables holding arrays, and methods `initialize` and `my_inspect`.

```
class Test
  def initialize
    @x = 1
    @array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    @tom_cat = ['Fluffy', 'Tiger', 'Max']
  end

  def my_inspect
    inspect.gsub(R,'')
  end
end
```

---

When `inspect` is invoked on an instance of `Test` we want no reference to instance variables holding arrays.

```
Test.new.inspect
  #=> "#<Test:0x00007f962c102740 @x=1>"
```

Voilà!

---

Another approach is to override the built-in `inspect`. There are two ways to do that. The first is create an alias for the built-in method `inspect`, as @MasaSakano has done in his/her answer. Another way is to prepend a module containing the new method `inspect`. I'll describe that option below.

The first step is to create a module with the new method `inspect` that will be prepended to the class `Test`.

```
module M  
  def inspect
    method(__method__).super_method
                      .call
                      .gsub(R,'')
  end
end
```

See [Kernel#__method__](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-__method__) and [Method#super_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Method.html#method-i-super_method).

---

Next create the class `Test` which prepends module `M`.

```
class Test
  def initialize
    @x = 1
    @array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    @tom_cat = ['Fluffy', 'Tiger', 'Max']
  end
  prepend M
end
```

See [Module#prepend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-prepend).

---

Try it!

```
Test.new.inspect
  #=> "#<Test:0x00007f962c852900 @x=1>"
```

Voilà again!

Answer (score 2):

Probably it's possible to use more elegance conversion for object id, but not sure by much

```rb
class Test
  def initialize
    @x = 1
    @array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  end

  def myinspect
    "#<#{self.class.name}:0x#{(object_id * 2).to_s(16).rjust(16, '0')} @x=#{instance_variable_get(:@x)}>"
  end
end
```

And then

```rb
test = Test.new

puts test.inspect
#<Test:0x000055e35c5dc4c0 @x=1, @array=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]>

puts test.myinspect
#<Test:0x000055e35c5dc4c0 @x=1>
```

Without this conversion your code will be not so ugly

For example [rails don't use](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/13d3fc9d323288b6db9294aedcc7eced02dd54f0/activerecord/lib/active_record/core.rb#L369-L383) this object id

Probably you don't need it too

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to ruby and I didn't knew about `object_id` or `instance_variable_get`. I've made an generic `inspect_except` using those. Will post the answer here